# Top-Level <:Body> Injections?

Tags: svelte

Imagine I have the following component, `<TopLevelThing>`.

```html
<div class="top-level-thing">
    <p>Top level stuff.</p>
</div>
```

It's intended to be used at the top-level of the `<body>`.

However, I might want to use it as part of a component which is deep inside the `<body>`, nowhere near the top-level.

This could be achieved with a special tag like the following.

```html
<:Body>
    <TopLevelThing />
</:Body>
```

Svelte would inject this into the top-level of the `<body>` alongside other elements. However, it would retain all the functionality of a component: the lifecycle, properties, and being part of the component organisation and structure.

Is something like this possible in Svelte?

As an aside, I imagine that this could be achieved with workarounds, but I was wondering whether there was a specific feature for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afraid not! Though you'd certainly be welcome to raise an issue for it so that we can discuss the use case and see what the best approach is. (No guarantees that the best approach isn't a hacky workaround :)

Comment: I've raised the issue [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1133). It may or may not be the appropriate solution to the problems it attempts to solve, but it's probably worth a discussion as you suggest.